# Bootstrap 4 multi item carousel not responsive, shows only one item in corner in desktop

Tags: javascript, css, carousel

I would like to add second carousel at the top, before hero, and one difference is that it should be multi item, but shows only one item.

Maybe its becouse of the bigger carousel with showing only one item per slide.

Bootstrap 4

```
    <div class="container-fluid mt-5">

  <!-- Grid row -->
  <div class="row">

    <!-- Grid column -->
    <div class="col-md-12 mb-4">

      <div class="container text-center my-3">
        <div class="row my-auto">
          <div id="recipeCarousel2" class="carousel slide w-100 " data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner w-100 vv-3" role="listbox">
              <div class="carousel-item active">
                <div class="col-2">
                  <img class="d-block img-fluid"
                    src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/images/43.jpg">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <div class="col-2">
                  <img class="d-block img-fluid"
                    src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/images/43.jpg">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <div class="col-2">
                  <img class="d-block img-fluid"
                    src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/images/43.jpg">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <div class="col-2">
                  <img class="d-block img-fluid"
                    src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/images/43.jpg">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <div class="col-2">
                  <img class="d-block img-fluid"
                    src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/images/43.jpg">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <div class="col-2">
                  <img class="d-block img-fluid"
                    src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/images/43.jpg">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#recipeCarousel2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
              <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#recipeCarousel2" role="button" data-slide="next">
              <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- Grid column -->

  </div>
  <!-- Grid row -->
  
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsVJT.png)

Comment: I have just added only html, maybe its not working becouse of the classes of carousel, becouse there is second bootstrap carousel with full desktop width of the item.

Answer (score 0):

### Single carousel using multiple image in bootstrap and Multiple carousel with multiple images in single row with different columns.

> Below, Carousel code in bootstrap. please let me know if you want the
> same or not.

**Carousel Using Multiple Images.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
 
  .carousel-inner img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ul>
  
  <!-- carousel slideshow -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/images/43.jpg" alt="" width="1100" height="500">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/images/43.jpg" alt="" width="1100" height="500">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/images/43.jpg" alt="" width="1100" height="500">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

---

**Multiple Carousel in a row with multiple columns in bootstrap.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>

  .carousel-inner img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
        <div id="carosel1" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carosel1" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carosel1" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carosel1" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ul>
  
  <!-- Carousel slideshow -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/images/43.jpg" width="100" height="50">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/images/43.jpg" width="100" height="50">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/images/43.jpg" width="100" height="50">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carosel1" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carosel1" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </a>
</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-4">
        <div id="carosel2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carosel2" data-slide-to="0"></li>
    <li data-target="#carosel2" data-slide-to="1" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carosel2" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ul>
  
  <!-- Carousle slideshow -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/images/43.jpg" width="100" height="50">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/images/43.jpg" width="100" height="50">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/images/43.jpg" width="100" height="50">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carosel2" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carosel2" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </a>
</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-4">
        <div id="carosel3" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carosel3" data-slide-to="0"></li>
    <li data-target="#carosel3" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carosel3" data-slide-to="2"  class="active"></li>
  </ul>
  
  <!-- Carousel slideshow -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/images/43.jpg" width="100" height="50">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/images/43.jpg" width="100" height="50">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/images/43.jpg" width="100" height="50">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carosel3" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carosel3" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </a>
</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```